# Repetición de consultas MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, subconsultas

La consulta SQL se repite y los usuarios se repiten por consiguiente :( y no me quiere validar cuando ya existe el usuario, anexo código:

PD: es un trabajo escolar sin necesidad de tanta seguridad como me comentan en preguntas anteriores!

```html
<?php 
 include 'head.php';
 $id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
 $username = $_POST['username']; 
 $name = $_POST['nombre']; 
 $email = $_POST['email']; 
 $phone = $_POST['telefono']; 
 $dui = $_POST['DUI']; 
 $fecha = $_POST['fecha_nac']; 
 $password = $_POST['password']; 
 $type = $_POST['tipo']; 
 $departamento = $_POST['departamento'];
 $buscarUsuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios
 WHERE username = $username";

 if (mysqli_num_rows($buscarUsuario)>0) {

 print "<script>alert(\"El usuario ya ha sido tomado.\");</script>";
 
}else{
     $formatos = array('.jpg', '.png');
                     $nombreArchivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
                     $nombreTmpArchivo = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
                     $ext = substr($nombreArchivo, strrpos($nombreArchivo, '.'));
                      if (in_array($ext, $formatos)){
                     if(move_uploaded_file($nombreTmpArchivo, "images/$nombreArchivo")){
             print "<script>alert(Imagen subida con éxito);window.location='../artesa/formsArtesa/catalogo.php';</script>";
            }else{
             print "<script>alert(Error al subir imagen, comprueba el directorio del archivo);</script>";
             }
            }else{
              print "<script>alert(Formato de imagen no aceptado, intenta con JPG y PNG)</script>";
            }
    $imagen=$nombreTmpArchivo;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (password, username, nombre, dui, email, telefono, fecha_nac, tipo, departamento, image) VALUES ('$password','$username','$name','$dui','$email','$phone','$fecha','$type','$departamento','images/$nombreArchivo')";
    $eject= $con->query($sql);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['id_user'] = $id_user;
    $_SESSION['t'] = $type;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
    $_SESSION['fecha_nac'] = $fecha;
    $_SESSION['departamento'] = $departamento;
    $_SESSION['DUI'] = $dui;

   if (isset($_SESSION['t'])) {
        switch ($_SESSION['t']) {
   case 'Ar':
    print "<script>alert(Bienvenido ".$_SESSION['username']."!)";
    header('location: formsArtesa/catalogo.php');
    break;
   case 'Cl':
    echo "<script>alert(Bienvenido ".$_SESSION['username']."!)";
    header('location: formsUser/catalogo.php');
    break;
    }
   }
 if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {

 echo "<br />" . "<h2>" . "Usuario Creado Exitosamente!" . "</h2>";

 echo "<h4>" . "Bienvenido: " . $_POST['username'] . "</h4>" . "\n\n";

 echo "<h5>" . "Logueate: " . "<a href='login.html'>Login</a>" . "</h5>";

 }else{

 echo "Error al crear el usuario." . $query . "<br>" . $con->error; 
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: El hecho de que sea un trabajo escolar no significa que el código tiene que ser inseguro. Además, cuando usas consultas preparadas es mucho más fácil y claro el código. Un poquito de esfuerzo en la etapa de aprendizaje no viene mal. Y hay ejemplos muy buenos para aprender las buenas prácticas.

Comment: Será de utilidad indiques que ocurre, mensaje(s) de error(es), algo que nos de una pista cual es el obstáculo que te detiene. Así de simple vista sin analizar mucho el código; tu *WHERE* le falta las comillas simples en *username = $username* toda vez que (seguro) es texto que deseas comparar.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por el dato, pero aún estoy un poco fresco en estos temas jajajaja

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas Gracias por el detalle!

Comment: De nada. Por ejemplo ese detalle que comenta Roberto no te habría pasado al usar consultas preparadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que sufres es debido a que ejecutas el contenido de `$sql` dos veces, allá donde deseas hacerlo y al final para comprobar que se hizo bien la consulta.

Primera vez:

```
/* ... */
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (password, username, nombre, dui, email, telefono, fecha_nac, tipo, departamento, image) VALUES ('$password','$username','$name','$dui','$email','$phone','$fecha','$type','$departamento','images/$nombreArchivo')";
$eject = $con->query($sql);
session_start();
/* ... */
```

Segunda vez:

```
/* ... */
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "<br />" . "<h2>" . "Usuario Creado Exitosamente!" . "</h2>";
/* ... */
```

Deberías usar el contenido de la variable que usaste para guardar el resultado de la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
/* ... */
$eject = $con->query($sql);
/* ... ... ...*/
if ($eject === true) {
  echo "<br />" . "<h2>" . "Usuario Creado Exitosamente!" . "</h2>";
/* ... */
```

De esta manera compruebas el resultado de la consulta sin ejecutarla nuevamente.

Además (aunque no influye en el problema de los registros duplicados) nunca te funcionará la comprobación del número de usuarios preexistentes porque quieres usar `mysqli_num_rows` sobre una cadena de caracteres que contiene una consulta SQL, no sobre el resultado de ejecutar la consulta.

Te adjunto el código PHP completo con todas las modificaciones realizadas:

```
<?php
include 'head.php';
$id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$name = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['telefono'];
$dui = $_POST['DUI'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha_nac'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$type = $_POST['tipo'];
$departamento = $_POST['departamento'];
$buscarUsuario = "
  SELECT * FROM usuarios
  WHERE username = '$username'
";
/* Debes hacer esto antes de usar "num_rows" */
$resultado = $con->query($buscarUsuario);

if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
    print "<script>alert(\"El usuario ya ha sido tomado.\");</script>";
} else {
    $formatos = array('.jpg', '.png');
    $nombreArchivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $nombreTmpArchivo = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $ext = substr($nombreArchivo, strrpos($nombreArchivo, '.'));
    if (in_array($ext, $formatos)) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($nombreTmpArchivo, "images/$nombreArchivo")) {
            print "<script>alert(Imagen subida con éxito);window.location='../artesa/formsArtesa/catalogo.php';</script>";
        } else {
            print "<script>alert(Error al subir imagen, comprueba el directorio del archivo);</script>";
        }
    } else {
        print "<script>alert(Formato de imagen no aceptado, intenta con JPG y PNG)</script>";
    }
    $imagen=$nombreTmpArchivo;
    $sql = "
      INSERT INTO usuarios (
        password,
        username,
        nombre,
        dui,
        email,
        telefono,
        fecha_nac,
        tipo,
        departamento,
        image
      ) VALUES (
        '$password',
        '$username',
        '$name',
        '$dui',
        '$email',
        '$phone',
        '$fecha',
        '$type',
        '$departamento',
        'images/$nombreArchivo'
      )
    ";
    $eject = $con->query($sql);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['id_user'] = $id_user;
    $_SESSION['t'] = $type;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
    $_SESSION['fecha_nac'] = $fecha;
    $_SESSION['departamento'] = $departamento;
    $_SESSION['DUI'] = $dui;

    if (isset($_SESSION['t'])) {
        switch ($_SESSION['t']) {
            case 'Ar':
            print "<script>alert(Bienvenido ".$_SESSION['username']."!)";
            header('location: formsArtesa/catalogo.php');
            break;
            case 'Cl':
            echo "<script>alert(Bienvenido ".$_SESSION['username']."!)";
            header('location: formsUser/catalogo.php');
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($eject === true) {
        echo "<br />" . "<h2>" . "Usuario Creado Exitosamente!" . "</h2>";

        echo "<h4>" . "Bienvenido: " . $_POST['username'] . "</h4>" . "\n\n";

        echo "<h5>" . "Logueate: " . "<a href='login.html'>Login</a>" . "</h5>";
    } else {
        echo "Error al crear el usuario." . $query . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias!!!!!! me sirvió lo de la comparación!!

Comment: Me alegra saberlo. Si te sirvió recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta :) Puedes hacerlo pulsando en la marca ✔ que hay en la parte superior izquierda de mi respuesta.

Comment: Listo :D gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que tus variables estén llegando bien

```
 /*CONEXION BASE DE DATOS*/

      $hotsdb = "localhost";    
      $bd = "nombre_base_de_datos";
      $usuario = "tu_usuario";    
      $pass = "tu_password";    

      $conexion = new mysqli($hotsdb, $usuario, $pass, $bd);

      if ($conexion->connect_errno) {

             echo "ERROR AL CONECTARSE {$conexion->connect_errno}";       
    }

 $id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
 $username = $_POST['username']; 
 $name = $_POST['nombre']; 
 $email = $_POST['email']; 
 $phone = $_POST['telefono']; 
 $dui = $_POST['DUI']; 
 $fecha = $_POST['fecha_nac']; 
 $password = $_POST['password']; 
 $type = $_POST['tipo']; 
 $departamento = $_POST['departamento'];

 $buscarUsuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = '".$username."'";
 $resultado = $conexion->query($buscarUsuario);

 if(count($resultado) > 0)
 {
    /*AQUI 
           VAS A COLOCAR TU 
                           CODIGO A EJECUTAR
    */
 }else{

    echo"<script> 
        alert ('El usuario ya ha sido tomado');
            window.location='tu_pagina.php';
    </script>";
 }

 ?>
```

Esto te sirve

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias! Lastimosamente no me llenó :(

Comment: Como.? no te funciono.?

Comment: no :( pero muchas gracias!!!